# As someone learning German, what should I put on my flash cards for each part of speech?

Tags: learning

What should I put on my German flash cards in order to know everything I'll need to know about that word?  For example, I know for nouns I need to make sure to learn the gender and plural forms, since those vary by word.

When I was learning Greek I had flash cards that also included the genitive form of nouns, and for verbs the different principal parts.  Should I also include the genitive form on my noun flashcards, or is plural and the definite article for the gender sufficient?  What about other parts of speech?

Comment: I'll leave an answer for someone who teaches German, but I use two different sets of flash cards - verbs and their prepositions (e.g. beitragen - zu), and irregular verbs and their perfect and prateritum forms (sometimes the er form too) (e.g. bringen - brachte - hat gebracht)

Answer (score 10):

**For nouns:**

- gender and plural
- strong/weak noun declension (1)

**For verbs:**

- past stem, complete spoken past phrase,

> > geben, gab, habe gegeben.

- Furthermore, if a specific preposition is required, then it makes
  sense to put it there. But not so much for **gehen** as it could be
  almost anything. And then, note if there is a self reference.

> > sich übergeben - to vomit
> >
> > übergeben - to hand over

- If you want to be precise then add the case pattern as well.

> > jmd(acc). erinnern an etw(acc)

**Adjectives**

- If irregular, then add the 3 forms (degrees of comparison):

> > hoch, höher, am höchsten

**Prepositions**

- the case that follows

---

(1) this is "advanced stuff" since a lot of Germans don't use these rules correctly in casual conversation, but it can be important if you want to be able to speak properly

Comment: Also add conjunctions: coordinating or subordinating.

And for verbs in higher levels: Konjunktiv if irregular.

Comment: Adding the Konjunktiv might be too much details, as the usage of the simple Konjunktiv is very seldom. 

I would also recommend learning prepositions by groups, not one by one, for example : aus bei mit nach seit von zu = always dative ;

Comment: Adding the case pattern is very important, I would not skip that one.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this question using the first thing that came to my mind: *Write down everything that stuns you*.

By that I mean: You don't need to write down things that are already clear to you. If you are already sure that *Mutter* is female, why should you write down the gender explicitly?

Keep as little information on the cards as possible.

Comment: Well, what happens if you forget that *Mutter* is female? It may be obvious to you now, but this is not necessarily true if you haven't used certain vocabulary for a while.

Comment: Well, we could go into the theory of learning vocab properly - and having worked as a trainer in that field I could tell you a lot about it, but I'll just say as much as: You do need to *learn* that stuff, but the cards are only there to *repeat*. So you only put stuff on them that you need to repeat over and over to memorize, and after some time, you'll ask yourself why you even put it on the card ("It's obvious!"). Things that are obvious to you at the point of writing the card (*after* having learned the relevant grammar) will still be obvious to you later.

Answer (score 0):

I think when adding all the cases of a noun and so on, you will feel frustrated and - most of all - bored very soon. I suggest you add complete sentences or phrases to your nouns on the card.
(Please pick only phrases from really German sources. It is very hard to get rid of mistakes you were taught.)